# D'Alembert's solution of a semi-infinite string with fixed end

Tags: classical-mechanics, string

The problem is as follows:

The equations that governs a semi-infinite string with a fixed end is as follows
\begin{equation}
u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx},
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u(x,0)=f(x),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u_t(x,0)=g(x),
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u(0,t)=0,
\end{equation}
where $0<x<\infty$, $t>0$, and $f(0)=g(0)=0.$ Firstly, do these results hold for $x < 0$? If so, why? Secondly, use the boundary condition at $x = 0$ to solve for $u(x, t)$.

My attempt at a solution:

I have found that the solution corresponds to $u(x,t)=\psi(x+ct)+\phi(x-ct)$, where
\begin{equation}
\psi(x)=\frac{1}{2}f(x)+\frac{1}{2c}\int^x_0g(y)dy+C,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\psi(x)=\phi(x)=\frac{1}{2}f(x)-\frac{1}{2c}\int^x_0g(y)dy-C,
\end{equation}
and $C$ is some constant of integration. I am not sure how to use the boundary condition to solve this problem. Additionally, I know that the solution holds for $x<0$, but I do not know exact details as to why this solution holds. Could somebody offer a solution to these two problems?

Comment: You can use D’Alembert formula on the whole real axis simply by extending to odd functions the initial conditions.

Comment: @ValterMoretti, sorry for the inconvenience, however, could you elaborate?

Comment: @aLLiteration I wrote a detailed answer...

Answer (score 1):

First consider the Cauchy problem on the whole real line. We are looking for a solution $\tilde{u}= \tilde{u}(t,x)$, where $(t,x) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, solving the D'Alembert equation
$$\tilde{u}_{tt}- c^2 \tilde{u}_{xx}=0$$
and satisfying initial conditions $$\tilde{u}(x,0) =\tilde{f}(x)\quad \mbox{and}\quad \frac{\partial\tilde{u}}{\partial t}(x,0)=\tilde{g}(x)$$ on the complete axis $\mathbb{R} \ni x$.

I assume natural regularity conditions: $\tilde{f} \in C^2(\mathbb{R})$, $\tilde{g} \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$, and  $\tilde{u} \in C^2(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$.

As you correctly said (passing to coordinates $v=x+ct$ and $w=x-ct$) one immediately sees that the general solution has always the form
$$\tilde{u}(x,t) = \tilde{\psi}(x+ct) + \tilde{\phi}(x-ct)\:.\tag{1}$$

From what you have already found we have that, imposing the initial conditions on the form (1) of the solution, it arises
\begin{equation}
\tilde{\psi}(x+ ct)=\frac{1}{2}\tilde{f}(x+ct)+\frac{1}{2c}\int^{x+ct}_0\tilde{g}(y)dy+C,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\tilde{\phi}(x- ct)=\frac{1}{2}\tilde{f}(x-ct)+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x-ct}^0\tilde{g}(y)dy+C',
\end{equation}
so that
$$\tilde{u}(x,t)= \frac{1}{2}(\tilde{f}(x+ct) + \tilde{f}(x-ct)) + \frac{1}{2c}\int^{x+ct}_{x-ct}\tilde{g}(y)dy+ C+ C'$$
Since $\tilde{u}(x,0)=\tilde{f}(x)$, it must be $C+C'=0$ and we end up with the celebrated **D'Alembert formula**:
$$\tilde{u}(x,t)= \frac{1}{2}(\tilde{f}(x+ct) + \tilde{f}(x-ct)) + \frac{1}{2c}\int^{x+ct}_{x-ct}\tilde{g}(y)dy\tag{2}$$
for $(x,t)\in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$.
The procedure to find this solution also proves that  the found $\tilde{u}$ is **unique** when $\tilde{f} \in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\tilde{g} \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and if searching for solutions $\tilde{u} \in C^2(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R})$.

Let us next consider the problem of finding $u(x,t)$
for $x\in [0,+\infty)$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}$, $u \in C^2([0,+\infty)\times \mathbb{R})$, satisfying the D'Alembert equation in
$[0,+\infty) \times \mathbb{R}$ together
with vanishing boundary conditions
$u(0,t)=0$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$,
and with initial conditions $f\in C^2([0,+\infty))$, $g\in C^1([0,+\infty))$
satisfying $f(0)=g(0)=0$ as well.

To find a solution of that problem, let us come back to the previous problem on the whole real line  where now $f$ and $g$ are extended to the whole real axis by requiring that they define **odd functions** there:
$$\tilde{f}(x) := f(x) \quad \mbox{if $x\geq 0$,}\quad \tilde{f}(x) := -f(-x) \quad \mbox{if $x\leq  0$}\:,$$
$$\tilde{g}(x) := g(x) \quad \mbox{if $x\geq 0$,}\quad \tilde{g}(x) := -g(-x) \quad \mbox{if $x\leq  0$}\:.$$
These functions turn out to be  as regular as it is required to apply the previous procedure (actually this fact is a bit tricky to be proved when analyzing the second derivative of $\tilde{f}$ at $x=0$, but I do not insist on these mathematical details, I just say that the initial conditions have to satisfy also the requirement ${f}''(0) =0$ in view of the very D'Alembert equation in order to permit the existence of a solution).
Let us focus on the solution (2) of this problem and consider the restriction
$$u(x,t) := \tilde{u}(x,t)\quad x\in [0,+\infty)\:, t \in \mathbb{R}.$$
This function, in addition to the regularity requirements, satisfies the D'Alembert equation in $[0,+\infty)\times \mathbb{R}$ and the initial conditions
$u(x,0) =f(x)$ and $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial t}(x,0)=g(x)$ for $x\in [0,+\infty)$.

Directly form (2), we also have that
$$u(0,t) =  \frac{1}{2}(\tilde{f}(ct) + \tilde{f}(-ct)) + \frac{1}{2c}\int^{0+ct}_{0-ct}\tilde{g}(y)dy =0$$
because $\tilde{f}$ and $\tilde{g}$ are odd functions.

In summary, the constructed function $u$ satisfies all requirements of the given Cauchy problem on $[0,+\infty)$.

The uniqueness issue can be analyzed by expoiting  a so-called *energy esimate*. In fact, one sees that the found solution is unique in the class of solutions with the considered regularity.

Comment: thank you for the detailed description, however, can I also ask, how does one use the boundary conditions to solve for $\phi(x)$, and subsequently $u(x,t).$

Comment: I do not understand your question. I used boudary conditions when I wrote "Directly form (2), we also have that "...

Comment: Yes @ValterMoretti, I understand, however, the problem also requires that I solve for the functions ϕ(x) and subsequently u(x,t), using the boundary conditions. However, I do not seem to see that in your solution.